# Prove countable sets have measure 0

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I have read a couple of proofs and they are all of some variations of this (https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Countable_Set_is_Null_Set_under_Lebesgue_Measure) idea. I was just wondering if we can just use countable additivity of measure and claim that since every singleton has measure $0$, they union has measure $0$. If this is possible, why no textbook uses it. If not, what is the problem of this proof.

Comment: Nothing wrong with it. Provided that you have already proven countable additivity. It's a special case of countable additivity, usually presented separately, and earlier, in an introductory course, to demonstrate a method of proof that  is used  repeatedly in this subject.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, to do that you have to prove that Lebesgue measure is in fact countably additive. And this is essentially a more complicated version of the usual argument that any countable set has Lebesgue measure zero -
 instead of covering the $n$th point with an interval of length $\epsilon\cdot 2^{-n}$, we cover the $n$th set with intervals of total length within $\epsilon\cdot 2^{-n}$ of the measure of that set - so it is usually presented later.